# return a value with the function some

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the javascript function some(), it only returns "true" or "false".

Is it possible to return the found value instead of a boolean value?

```
        function myFunction() {

            let result;

            result = Object.keys( myObject ).some( function ( tmp ) {

                if ( condition[ tmp ] === true ) {

                    return tmp; // i would like to return the value of tmp

                }

            });

            alert( result ); // returns "true" or "false" but not the value of "tmp"

        }

Thank you !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
        function myFunction() {

            let result;

            result = Object.keys( myObject ).find( function ( tmp ) {

                if ( condition[ tmp ] === true ) {

                    return tmp; // i would like to return the value of tmp

                }

            });

            alert( result ); // returns "true" or "false" but not the value of "tmp"

        }
```